# When do I use libmysql-6.1.dll vs libmysql.dll?

Tags: mysql, heidisql

I'm using HeidiSQL to edit a MYSQL database, and it's asking which library I want to use for the edits:

1. libmysql-6.1.dll
2. libmysql.dll

How do I know which one to use?

Answer (score 6):

These alternative `libmysql*.dll` and `libmariadb*.dll` libraries are there to solve (SSL) connectivity issues on newer MySQL and MariaDB servers. For example on MySQL 5.7, some users [reported](https://github.com/HeidiSQL/HeidiSQL/issues/722) the following error with the older `libmysql.dll`:

```
ASN: bad other signature confirmation
```

Using libmariadb.dll *may* cause another error:

```
Unknown SSL error (0x80090308)
```

Especially when you provide a SSL certificate, you may run into such issues.

**For this and any other connectivity issue, HeidiSQL provides alternative libraries the user can try.** Apart from that, I never heard of any other advantage or disadvantage of one or another of these libraries.

Comment: It's not very clear if you're suggesting one should use `libmysql-6.1.dll` or `libmysql.dll`, which was OP's question. On a fresh install of HeidiSQL it defaults to `libmariadb.dll` so it's hard to know which MySQL library is intended to be the 'default' and most compatible with the latest version(s) of MySQL 8.

Comment: The default library is libmariadb.dll, since several Heidi versions. The OP did not mention MySQL v8, just MySQL, which for some users even imply MariaDB. However, due to a myriad of issues, related to SSL, authentication plugins, version incompatibilities and more, it's impossible to say which one is the best fitting one - for me as well. So my recommendation is to try out the others if the default one does not work.

Comment: Would be great to get clarification what the differences between `libmysql-6` and `libmysql` are actually. The naming would indicate something "version" - but if its not the case maybe it should be just renamed to `libmysql-alt` ? or `libmysql-fix` ?

MariaDB and MySQL are not fully compatible, but I also have no idea if that even makes any difference on the client library...

Answer (score 1):

While the question of which library to use for MariaDB seems pretty obvious (libmariadb.dll), what to make of the other two?

As a clue, I looked a the file properties.

```
libmysql.dll shows ProductVersion 5.6.6.0
libmysql-6.1.dll shows ProductVersion 6.1.11.0
```

Given that these files are included in HeidiSql v11.3, I concluded they are NOT generated by building HeidiSql.  So, where did those version numbers come from?

Poking around in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib`, I see a libmysql.dll there too (ProductVersion 8.0.25).

So, my guess is that HeidiSql acquired those files from builds of MySQL.  And the newer one (libmysql-6.1.dll) is probably the better bet for current releases of MySQL.

That does leave open the question of where the number "6.1" came from.  It doesn't appear there was ever a 6.1 release of MySQL?

And it also doesn't address which one is best for MSSQL, PostgreSQL, etc.  But that wasn't the question here.

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions of MySQL (8.x) -> use MariaDB.dll